# Designing Unique Keys(Primary Keys) for a heavily denormalized NoSQL database

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, nosql

I am working on a web application related to Discussion forums using Java and Cassandra database.

I need to construct 'keys' for the rows  storing the user's details and & another set of rows storing the content posted by the user.

One option is to get the randomly generated UUID provided by Java language, but these are 16 bytes long. and since NoSQL database involves heavy denormalization, I am concerned whether I would be wasting lots of disk space, RAM and other resources if the key could be generated in smaller sizes.

I need to generate two types of keys, one  for the  Users &  other for Content Posted by Users.

For the Content posted by users, would  `timestamp+userId` be a good key. where `timestamp` is the server time at which content was posted and `userId` refers to key of user row.

Any suggestions, comments appreciated ..

Thanks 
Marcos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a distributed application?

Then you could use a simple synchronized counter and initialize it on startup with the next available id.

On the other hand a database should be able to handle the UUID hashes as created by java.
This is a standard for creating things like sessionIds, that need to be unique.
Your problem is somewhat similar since a session in your context would represent a set of user input.

Comment: Thanks Oliver !! Yes this is a distributed application with a distributed database Cassandra. Since this database is eventually consistent, the synchronization may not be very fast and this may lead to problems as the data for that id may be overridden. But it is also possible to tune the consistency level in Cassandra, I'll look into that if that leads to a feasible solution. Is there any other alternative besides this?

Comment: For the Ids of the posts should I generate them using combination of 'userId' & 'Posts count of that user' like this userId:PostCountOfUser

Comment: using the userId as part of your sounds like a good idea in your scenario. Depending on your data representation it could also enable you to search faster for all posts of a user.
(I guess you can assume a user is only logged on once, and entering posts in one session at a time)